# Django : querying data from related models

Tags: python, django

I use Django 3.2.7 and I would like to query all orders from a customer.

Models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS=(
        ('Pending','Pending'),
        ('Out for Delivery','Out for delivery'),
        ('Delivered','Delivered'),
    )
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)
```

Views.py

```
def customer(request,pk):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    orders = customer.order_set.all()
    

    my_context={
        'customer':customer,
        'orders':orders
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/customer.html', context=my_context)
```

Urls.py

```
path('customer/<str:pk>/', views.customer),
```

Template

```
 {% for order in orders %}

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {order.product}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {order.product.category}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {order.date_created}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {order.status}
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="">Update</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>

                {% endfor %}
```

My problem is that instead of printing the actual data on the template is prints the query data.

I think the problem is at

```
orders = customer.order_set.all()
```

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Use double {{ }} in your template.

Comment: It was that easy. Thank you :)